# How to pass value of button to the function in react

Tags: reactjs

I want that on clicking the button X its value X pass to the result  function(same with O) where I can store it in a variable. I don't know how to pass this value on calling result and access it there. I tried to find many answers but none worked.
I'm absolutely new to react. Please help!! Thanks!! 
This is code snippet

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './App.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';



class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <h1 align="center">Welcome to TicTacToe</h1>
      <br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br>
      <div class="front">
      Choose your sign !!
      <CheckBox type='submit' value='X' id='x' onSubmit={'how to pass value'}/>
      <CheckBox type='submit' value='O' id='o' onSubmit={'how to pass value'}/>
      </div>
      <br></br>
      <Link to= "game"><p class="wrap"><button class="button">GO</button></p></Link>
      {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class CheckBox extends Component{
 result(i){
   //what to access value
 }



  render(){
    return (
    <div className={'check-field'}>
    <button type={this.props.type} value={this.props.value} name={this.props.name} id={this.props.id}>{this.props.value}</button>
    </div>
  );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The given answer is explaining your basic needs nicely. I advise you before trying to write some complex React code, just read the documentation a little bit deeply and follow some React tutorials out there. For your question, your Checkbox' design is not clear we can't say anything more by just looking your code like that. Again, @sarneeh's answer is good enough for standard procedures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem properly, but to get a value from a child input component (input/button/textarea) in its parent, just pass a prop with a function which will be called in the child on any `onClick`/`onChange` callback function. Here's a little example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  onSubmit(value) {
    // I have the button value here!
    console.log(value);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (    
      <div>
        <Button value="X" onSubmit={this.onSubmit} />
        <Button value="O" onSubmit={this.onSubmit} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Button extends React.Component {
  onClick(event) {
    const value = event.target.value;
    this.props.onSubmit(value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button value={this.props.value} onClick={e => this.onClick(e)}>
        {this.props.value}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" />
```

I hope this solves your problem!

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I got to understand the problem. It's now working fine!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can store for each checkbox value in state of App. Then, when checkbox is subimtted value it will call handleSubmit and event parameter e holds value and id of checkbox. In your case you can examine if it's X or Y and setState accordingly. This will re-render checkboxes who will via props get proper values.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


class App extends Component {
  state = {
     X : false,
     Y : false
  }
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
     if(e.target.id === 'x') {
       this.setState({X:true});
     } else {
       this.setState({Y:true});
     }
  }
  render() {
    const { X,Y } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 align="center">Welcome to TicTacToe</h1>
        <br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br>
       <div class="front">
          Choose your sign !!
         <CheckBox type='submit' value={X} id='x' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
         <CheckBox type='submit' value={Y} id='o' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
      </div>
      <br></br>
      <Link to= "game"><p class="wrap"><button class="button">GO</button></p></Link>
      {this.props.children}
     </div>
    );
  }
}

class CheckBox extends Component{
 render(){
    const {value, type, name, id} = this.props;
    return (
       <div className={'check-field'}>
         <button type={type} value={value} name={name} id={id}>{value}</button>
       </div>
    );
  } 
}

export default App;
```